# Objective-C Constant variable not work, occurs "Property not found on object of type"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

In Java, the following code is fine, no error.

```
class ConstantA{
  public static String MY_TEST = "My Test";
}
```

---

```
import ConstantA;
Class TestClass{
  public void test(){
    System.out.println(ConstantA.MY_TEST); // it's work fine.
 }
}
```

According to above java concept, it doesn't work on Objective-C,

in ConstantA.h file

```
extern NSString * const MY_TEST;
@interface ConstantA : NSObject
@end
```

in ConstantA.m file

```
NSString * const MY_TEST = @"My Test";
@implementation ConstantA
@end
```

in main.m file ( error occurs here)

```
#import "ConstantA.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
       NSLog(@"%@",ConstantA.MY_TEST); // error: Property 'MY_TEST' not found on object of type 'ConstantA'
    }
}
```

Can help me to solve this problem?
thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#import "ConstantA.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"%@", MY_TEST); // error: Property 'MY_TEST' not found on object of type 'ConstantA'
    }
}
```

Use directly the global variable, without class name:
**MY_TEST** and NOT ConstantA.MY_TEST.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSLog(@"%@",MY_TEST);`.

`MY_TEST` is not scoped by `ConstantA` in any way; it's simply a global variable. Objective-C doesn't support class-level "static variables" like you'd find in Java or C++. Classes can only have instance variables

You can sorta imitate a class variable with a global variable, but it's still just a global; it's not namespaced to the class in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Global string in the .h file
property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *gMyString;

In the .m file
synthetize gMyString;

It should work... I had the same problem last week !